# Is there a ruby-er way to do these assignments?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to read Sonar report in XML format using ruby. I have written the following code:

```
class Resource
    attr_accessor :file_name, :lines, :generated_lines, :ncloc, :generated_ncloc, :statements, :comment_lines, :commented_out_code_lines, :lines_to_cover, :uncovered_lines, :conditions_to_cover, :uncovered_conditions, :line_coverage, :branch_coverage, :coverage, :test_success_density, :test_failures, :skipped_tests, :test_errors, :num_of_tests, :lang, :qualifier

    def to_s
        "#{@name} #{@lines} #{@generated_lines} #{@ncloc} #{@generated_ncloc} #{@statements} #{@comment_lines} #{@commented_out_code_lines} #{@lines_to_cover} #{@uncovered_lines} #{@conditions_to_cover} #{@uncovered_conditions} #{@line_coverage} #{@branch_coverage} #{@coverage} #{@test_success_density} #{@test_failures} #{@skipped_tests} #{@test_errors}#{@num_of_tests} #{@lang} #{@qualifier}"
    end 
end


sonar.root.each_element do |node1| # resources
    next if node1.name != "resources"
    node1.each_element do |node2| #resource
        resource = Resource.new
        resource.lang = node2.text if node2.name == "lang"
        resource.qualifier = node2.text if node2.name == "qualifier"
        resource.name = node.text if node2.name == "name"
    end
end
```

As you can see this takes up too many statements whether I use `if` conditionals or `case` statements. Is there a more succinct way of doing this in ruby?

Comment: What XML parser are you using?

Comment: This might shorten it up a bit `resource.send("#{node2.name}=", node2.text)`

Answer (score 1):

Filter the nodes first instead of switching while iterating. And since you’re doing the same thing for each possible value of the `name` attribute, DRY that up with a loop too.

```
sonar.root.each_element_with_attribute 'name', 'resources' do |node1|
  %w[lang qualifier name].each do |name_val|
    node1.each_element_with_attribute 'name', name_val do |node2|
      resource = Resource.new
      resource.public_send :"#{name_val}=", node2.text
    end
  end
end
```

<sub>Note: I’m assuming you’re using REXML from your code and your lack of answer to my comment as of this writing. I would, however, suggest you use the friendlier [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) instead.</sub>

Comment: Need to append '=' to the method send, I think

Comment: @enthrops You’re right, good catch.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Let me try this and get back. Also, will check out Nokogiri.

Comment: Hi Andrew, this seems to be based on attributes. My xml is of the following pattern:
    <msr>
        <key>lines</key>
        <val>77854.0</val>
        <frmt_val>77,854</frmt_val>
    </msr>

Comment: @KarthickS You should probably include sample XML in your question. Don’t expect us to magically know your data format.

Comment: Makes Sense. Sorry for not posting it earlier:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resources>
<resource>
<id>123456</id>
<key>IdentifyingKey</key>
<name>NameOfFile</name>
<lname>FullNameOfFile</lname>
<scope>Project</scope>
<qualifier>Tracker</qualifier>
<lang>Fortran</lang>
<version>1.0</version>
<date>DateStamp</date>
<msr>
<key>lines</key>
<val>10000</val>
<frmt_val>10,000</frmt_val>
</msr>
</resource>
</resources>